# Javascript Discord Bot Error (Function Error)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I always get an error message after adding the reload command.
Without the Reload Command, the bot works with all commands without any problems
Without the Reload Command, the bot works with all commands without any problems
I just can't find the mistake

The error message:

> ```
> undefined commands found.
> /home/runner/Discord-BreakpointBot/index.js:19
>    delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${f}`)]; 
>                                ^
>
> TypeError: require.resolve is not a function
> ```

Code:

```
function loadCmds () { 
  fs.readdir('./commands/', (err, files) => { 
    if(err) console.error(err); 

    var jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split('.').pop() === 'js'); 
    if (jsfiles.length <=0) {return console.log('No commands found...')} 
    else {console.log(jsfiles.lenght + ' commands found.')} 

    jsfiles.forEach((f,i) => { 
      delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${f}`)]; 
      var cmds = require(`./commands/${f}`); 
      console.log(`Command ${f} loading...`); 
      bot.commands.set(cmds.config.command, cmds); 
    })
  })
}


bot.on('message', message => {

  var sender = message.author; 
  var msg = message.content.toUpperCase(); 
  var prefix ='>' 
  var cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" "); 
  var args = cont.slice(1); 

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return; 

  var cmd = bot.commands.get(cont[0]) 
  if (cmd) cmd.run(bot, message, args); 

  if (msg === prefix + 'RELOAD') {
    message.channel.send({embed:{description:"All Commands Reloaded"}}) 
    message.channel.send('All Commands Reloaded')
    loadCmds()
  }

});

loadCmds();
// Bot Launched
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot Launched...') 

  bot.user.setStatus('Online')
  bot.user.setActivity('https://www.twitch.tv');
});
```

I hope someone can help, thanks

Comment: Did you make sure the `require` dependency is available in your script?

Comment: Yes its added in the package

Comment: Based off the error, `require` does not have a `resolve` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what causes your `error` but I can offer you my method of retrieving comamnds, which works pretty well:

```js
const fileArray = [];

    function readCommands(dir) {

        const __dirname = rootDir;

        // Read out all command files
        const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));

        // Loop through all the files in ./commands
        for (const file of files) {
            // Get the status of 'file' (is it a file or directory?)
            const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));

            // If the 'file' is a directory, call the 'readCommands' function
            // again with the path of the subdirectory
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                readCommands(path.join(dir, file));
            }
            else {
                const fileDir = dir.replace('\\', '/');
                fileArray.push(fileDir + '/' + file);
                // fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(cmdFile => cmdFile.endsWith('.js'));
            }
        }
    }


    readCommands('commands');

    for(const file of fileArray) {
        const command = require(`../${file}`);

        if(command.name) {
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

This will **recursively** search the folder you specify when calling the function and then store it in `fileArray`.

*This solution is more an alternative than an exact solution to the error you are experiencing*